# Is there an in-game catalog?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Previous entries into the Animal Crossing series offered an in-game catalog at Nook's shop where I could review all of the items I've obtained in the game.  In New Leaf, the shops have changed dramatically and I'm not sure if this feature is still in the game.

Is there a catalog in New Leaf?  And if so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The catalog in New Leaf doesn't unlock until you upgrade the Nookling Junction to T&T Mart. This will unlock the catalog machine, which functions in the same way as previous entries in the series did, letting you order (most) items that you've previously collected/sold.

In order to upgrade Nookling Junction to T&T Mart, you must meet the following requirements:

- Complete the 10,000 Bell house down payment
- Spend 12,000 bells at Nookling Junction
- Either 7 or 10 days need to have passed since town creation.

The [Animal Crossing Wikia](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/T%26T_Mart) states 7, but [Nookipedia](http://nookipedia.com/wiki/T%26T_Mart) states 10. Other sources I can find also state 10, but it'll be difficult to verify whether or not this has changed from the Japanese version until sufficient time has passed from the release date.

Comment: Is spending ★12,000 per player or cumulative amongst all players in a village?

Comment: @CyberSkull As far as I know, it works the same as in past games, which counted for all residents in a single village. There's a finite inventory every day (minus the stationery, which you can buy more than one stack of), so it would make sense that it doesn't matter who buys it, as long as it is bought and money is spent there.

Comment: @FAE After ten days, my Nookling Junction announced plans to upgrade. Thanks!